# Auto refresh table body every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created a website using app script.

I need the table to automatically refresh every 3 seconds. (Just the table not the whole page)

How can I do it?

Here my code:

```js
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getOnline();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getOnline).generateTable();

});

function generateTable(dataArray){

  var tbody = document.getElementById("tablebody");
  
  dataArray.forEach(function(r){
  
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var col1 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.textContent = r[0];
  var col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col2.textContent = r[1];
  var col3 = document.createElement("td");
  col3.textContent = r[2];
  row.appendChild(col1);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  row.appendChild(col3);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
  
  
  });
}

</script>
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
```

```html
<h1> Current Users</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>EID</th>
      </tr>
     <tbody id="tablebody">
    </table>
```

The values on the table body came from my spreadsheet. But apparently, every time I input some values in my spreadsheet I still need to refresh the whole page in order for me to see the value in the table. How can I do it? Thank you so much! Happy new year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  setInterval(() => {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getOnline();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getOnline).generateTable();
  }, 3000); // run the function every 3 seconds
  
});
```

You can consider using `setInterval` method to refresh your table's data source every 3 seconds. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: thanks, that help me out, i tried your suggestion and i get the value what i want. but the new problem is, that will make new table and the old table stay on my page. i want the old table get replace with new table and so on.

Comment: During the initiation of that script, you can empty the element. That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying over the same script with a single change.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  setInterval(() => {
document.getElementById("tablebody").innerHTML = "";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getOnline();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getOnline).generateTable();
  }, 3000); // run the function every 3 seconds
  
});
```

You can do something like this.

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you so much! Happy new year bro!